# ActionScript: Determine wether superclass implements a particular interface?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any non-hacky way to determine wether a class' superclass implements a particular interface?

For example, assume I've got:

```
class A extends EventDispatcher implements StuffHolder {
    protected function get myStuff():Stuff { ... };

    public function getStuff():Array {
        if (super is StuffHolder) // <<< this doesn't work
            return super['getStuff']().concat([myStuf]);
        return [myStuff];
}

class B extends A {
    override protected function get myStuff():Stuff { ... };
}
```

How could I perform that `super is StuffHolder` test in a way that, well, works? In this case, it always returns `true`.

Comment: What if you try to cast it as StuffHolder instead of checking? Something like if(super as StuffHolder)?

Comment: Nope, no love - `super` appear to have too much magic to do that.

Comment: If EventDispatcher implemented StuffHolder, you wouldn't be able to compile that without an 'override' modifier for A's getStuff.. Meaning super would have it, anyway..

Inheritance is checked at compilation time, isn't it? Why would you not know if parent implements some class?

Comment: @Kishi: Because `getStuff` might be called on either an `A` OR a `B`. If it's called on a `B` it should call `super.getStuff()`, but if it's called on an `A`, it shouldn't call `super.getStuff()`.

Comment: this isn't how things work. the implementation of a method is always in the context of the implementing class. and within A, super always is scoped to A's superclass. also, the code really makes very little sense to me. what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Uuhh… So, @back2dos, you're right - what I'm trying to do makes no sense at all. I was trying to implement a kind of tree using mixins with `import`… But it turns out that, as you said, this code makes no sense at all.

Comment: So, thanks for the help guys, even though I'm crazy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you might have to define StuffHolder (and have it extend EventDispatcher) as a class and have getStuff as a public/protected function. You could then overload the getStuff function in class A, but not in class B.

```
package {
 public class StuffHolder extends EventDispatcher {
  function StuffHolder() {

  }
  protected function getStuff():Array{
   return ["Default"];
  }
 }
}
package {
 public class A extends StuffHolder {
  function A {
   super();
  }
  protected override function getStuff():Array {
   return ["A"];
  }
 }
}
package {
 public class B extends StuffHolder {
  function B {
   super();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that you can't do multiple inheritance with AS3, which I think would help in your case. This post may also help you. http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/10/multiple-inheritance-in-actionscript-3.cfm good luck!

Comment: Yup, that's the problem. In my case, the `getStuff` function is actually a mixin that's being implemented via an `include "..."`, so I don't want to change the superclasses of the stuff I'm extending.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the full picture to figure out why you'd need that kind of (weird and possibly broken) inheritance, but could you rephrase it to *if (this is actually an A instance)*?

If so, you could go with...

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

if (getQualifiedClassName(this) == 'A')
```

The thing is, the *is* operator should be used on object instances. And it works all the way up to object -- I mean, *A is B* is true for every *A* ancestor or interface implementation.

I think you could come up with a better structure for your classes, though.
This isn't that pretty.

Comment: As I mentioned on Sandro's comment, my `getStuff` function is actually a mixin that's being `include "..."`'d, so it doesn't even know what class it's on. The only thing it knows is that the class that it's being applied to has implemented the `StuffHolder` interface.

Comment: Omg.. It's getting even uglier.
Alright. So.. Is "if (super.foo != null) super.foo()" enough?
Or do you need to know if it _really_ implements StuffHolder?

If so... Reflection. "describeType(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedSuperclassName(this)))" will return the superclass (EventDispatcher, in the A class, for example) XML description. It'll have a "<factory />" tag with a list of it's implemented interfaces...

Answer (score 0):

I could do something involving introspection, getting the current class, finding its parent class, then checking to see if that implements the `StuffHolder` interface… But that seems pretty ugly :(